# How to tell if polygons are interlocked?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider an arrangement of nonoverlapping concave polygons. For instance here are two different arrangements.

[image]

Any single polygon is "interlinked" in the sense that it can't be moved apart if the others remain stationary. However, the arrangement on the left can be separated, but the one on the right can't; it is "interlocked".

[image]

Is there a way to calculate whether an "interlinked" arrangement is "interlocked" or not? Are there existing computer algorithms to determine this? How about for polyhedra in 3D? (See for example "coordinated motion puzzle".)

Comment: I think that's NP-hard, and you should ask this on CSE or SO to get better answers, since it's much related to coding.

Comment: @Trebor: how on earth you conjecture that the OP is asking about an NP-hard problem defeats me, as I have no idea what the OP is talking about. To the OP, what do mean by "concave", "interlinked", "interlocked", "separated" etc.

Comment: @RobArthan: I don't think the original post is particularly ambiguous? If you want a more formal definition, say that a collection $C$ of disjoint polygons $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ is interlinked with respect to $P_k$ if there is no continuous motion of $P_k$ (i.e., a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1$ which gives for each time $t$ a position and orientation, and a function $g(t)$ giving the image of $P_k$ under this transformation) which leaves $P_k$ disjoint from all other $P_i$ at all times and moves $P_k$ arbitrarily far from the other polygons in $C$ over time.

Comment: Say that $C$ is interlocked if there is no collection of continuous functions $f_i(t)$ giving the position and orientation of $P_i$ at time $t$ (and $g_i(t)$ giving the actual polygons at time $t$) such that $g_1(t),\ldots,g_n(t)$ are disjoint for all $t$ and $\limsup_{t\to\infty}\text{min}_{i,j}(\text{dist}(g_i(t),g_j(t))=\infty$, where we measure the distance between two polygons as the minimum distance between two points in the polygons.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Thank you. Those definitions are all new to me. I expect they will be new to many other MSE users too. Do you have references?

Comment: @JairTaylor That's about as clear as mud to me. I think you have missed a negative in your discussion of "interlocked". I think some rigour is necessary, because the question as stated is meaningless to someone (like me) who doesn't have any insight into the moves that you are allowing to separate the polygons.

Comment: @RobArthan You're right, I missed a negative. Let me try again.

Comment: The polygons are interlocked if, were you to cut these shapes out of wood, say, and put them in this arrangement on a table, you could not separate them without lifting the pieces or breaking them. You can move them however you wish as long as you don't lift the pieces from the table. There are various ways of making this rigorous but it's not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually worked out what the OP meant. I think the word "concave" in the question remains irrelevant and deeply confusing. I think this is an excellent example of a good MSE question that has been very poorly expressed.

Comment: Agreed that the word "concave" is irrelevant... probably the OP means something like "not-necessarily-convex".

Comment: Are you interested only in the case of 4 polygons?